# Do something after Action is completed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a problem with SpriteKit.
I am having an animation that rund through seven pictures. It is showing the aiming process of an unit. After the process is done i want to start a method i implemented. Does anyone know how i can find out when the Action is done?

```
    func shootAnmination(){
    var array:[SKTexture] = []
    for x in 1...6{
        array.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: ("fire" + String(x))))
    }
    let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(array, timePerFrame: 0.5)
    let unitFire = SKAction.repeatAction(animation, count: 1)

    self.runAction(unitFire)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as i know there is no way to find out when an action finished but you can use

```
func runAction(_ action: SKAction, completion block: () -> Void)
```

to start your method. The completion block is called after the action finished.

Comment: This is the method I would prefer to use,  The only issue with this is if you have a sequence going,  this won't fire till the very end of the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use SKAction.sequence/1 and SKAction.runBlock/1 to perform an action after your repeat action:

```
let animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(array, timePerFrame: 0.5)
let unitFire = SKAction.repeatAction(animation, count: 1)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([unitFire,SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in
            // your code
        })])
```

self.runAction(unitFire)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this implementation and it does just what its supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to use a timer ( 0.5 sec * 7 )
something like

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3.5, target: self, selector: "timerDidFire:", userInfo: userInfo, repeats: false)
```

Comment: Timers are a bad idea because 1) it does not instantly fire,  there are some delays which can cause the timer to fire out of sync of animation. 2) You need to manage it for when you exit/come back from an app, as well as manage it when dealing with a pause state.  3) If the app starts to lag,  the timer does not lag, which could cause the timer to fire too early

Comment: u r right, ill leave it here so people c the reasons not to use timers :)

Answer (score 1):

Use self.runAction with completion block: Here is the Objective C code:

```
[node runAction:moveUp completion:^{
    NSLog(@"RUNNING MOVE DOWN");
    [node setHidden: NO];
    [node runAction: moveDown];
}];
```